# Android: do activity lifecycle events stop methods which are running?

Tags: android, file, methods, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

What happens if some activity lifecycle events occur while a method is executing?
My activity has some methods where JSON text files (few tens of Kb) are written to disk, for example. Is it wrong designed? 
Or, in general, consider the case where there are two instructions to be executed: the first performs an important operation, the second  updates some data based on the result from the first.

Something like:

```
value=performOperationAndYeldResult();
updateAppData(value);
```

What happens if the lifecycle event occurrs after the first call and before the second, or while it's executing?
I put "long" operations in services but I cannot create a service for every critical data update all over the app. I think I am missing something so I fear for nothing. Maybe the resumed or restarted activity continues operations so they get completed.
Anyway I ask here: Are methods completed, or continued?

Comment: It's highly recommended to put long running operations in Service. Why can't you use a Service?

Comment: The operations are taking place in UI thread? If yes, I would suggest to execute them in a secondary thread. Taking place in a secondary thread is safe, the thread will keep running even the activity is destroyed.

Comment: Or as per @NitinSethi reply, use a Service or better an AsyncTask. For the writing operation I would suggest to implement an AsyncTask. Read about how it can be used. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: AsyncTask is not better for running long task. It is recommended only for short operations which run for a "few" seconds as per the API docs.

Comment: "few tens of Kb" does not take very long I guess...He already said that long operation are taking place in a Service, but you can't create a Service for any operation of 10 seconds time

Answer (score 0):

```
new PerformOperationAsyncTask(someValue);

private class PerformOperationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object> {

        protected Long doInBackground(Object... values) {

            //this is taking place in secondary thread          
             Object returnValue = performOperationAndYeldResult(values[0]);

             return returnValues;
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
             //this is taking place in the UI thread
             updateAppData(value);
         }
     }
```